# Cross join for time series postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table with Items with

```
Item_id,  Item_time,             Item_numbers
  1       2017-01-01 18:00:00       2
  2       2017-01-01 18:10:00       2
  3       2017-01-01 19:10:00       3
```

I want to group the items by hourly for some specific time (between 9 to 3 for each day) and in case if there is no entry for the particular hours then it should it be a 0.

Desired Output:

```
            Item_time          Item_numbers
         2017-01-01 18:00:00       4
         2017-01-01 19:00:00       3 
         2017-01-01 20:00:00       0    



with hour_items as (select date_trunc('hour', item_time) "hour",
avg(item_numbers) as value from items where item_id=2 and
fact_time::date= '2017-01-01' group by hour) select hour, value from
hour_items where EXTRACT(HOUR FROM hour) >= '9' and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM
> hour) < '15'.
```

The above query groups them correctly but the where the hour is missing, there is no entry. Though it should be an entry with a 0 as stated in the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do.

We get all the distinct days (CTE dates), then we generate hours for each of those dates (CTE hours) and finally we left join our data on "per our" basis.

```
with sample_data as (
    select 1 as item_id, '2018-01-01 12:03:15'::timestamp as item_time, 2 as item_numbers
    union all
    select 2 as item_id, '2018-01-01 12:41:15'::timestamp as item_time, 1 as item_numbers
    union all
    select 3 as item_id, '2018-01-01 17:41:15'::timestamp as item_time, 2 as item_numbers
    union all
    select 4 as item_id, '2018-01-01 19:41:15'::timestamp as item_time, 2 as item_numbers
),
dates as (
    select distinct item_time::date
    from sample_data
),
hours as (
    select item_time + interval '1 hour' * a as hour
    from dates
    cross join generate_series(0,23) a
)
select h.hour, sum(coalesce(sd.item_numbers,0))
from hours h
left join sample_data sd on h.hour = date_trunc('hour', sd.item_time)
where extract(hour from hour) between 9 and 17
group by h.hour
order by h.hour
```